# How to install Medacy on the machine.?

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am facing problems like git link not working. Package missing and all.
Link from where I am downloading.

https://github.com/NLPatVCU/medaCy

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing worked.

Hi all.
Make sure you update your spacy model. Then follow up instructions to install medacy.
Like this

`python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

```
from medacy.model.model import Model

model = Model.load_external('medacy_model_clinical_notes')
annotation = model.predict("Karan Advil boy")
print(annotation)
```